# Unable to apply multiple objectlistview filters chosen by user

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview

I am attempting to add an Excel like filtering option to a program that is processing 3 xml files and optionally an xls file. One of the problems I am running into is finding good examples of applying multiple filters at once. I understand that Filter.Chain allows for multiple "pre-built" filters to be applied at once, the main trouble is being able to dynamically create the filters then applying them. For example, one of the things being looked at by the program is vehicle makes such as Honda, Ford, etc and I would like to be able to select which makes I want to see in the ObjectListView.

Due to the amount of code in use it is hosted at pastebin:
    [Main Gui](http://pastebin.com/YZaxWQrf)
    [Worker Script](http://pastebin.com/Zny8kz7d)
    [Input Panel](http://pastebin.com/ykaMBWCQ)
    [Primary Output](http://pastebin.com/LnZa3BDN)
    [Secondary Output](http://pastebin.com/KNKNeP9U)

What I am hoping to find are examples of how I would be able to add an Excel like filtering. Currently I have a menu option set that opens a MultiChoiceDialog window which provides a list of options, but I am unable to find a good pythonic way of taking the selections and applying them as a filter or series of filters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are reading an Excel file into your ObjectListView widget. I think it would be easier to load the data into a sqlite database and then use SQL commands to do your filtering. I prefer using SQLAlchemy. That way I can create a class that represents the data that I can use both for SQLAlchemy and for my ObjectListView widget.

You can read about some of this sort of thing in the following articles:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/04/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-loading-random-sqlite-databases-for-viewing/
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/11/10/wxpython-and-sqlalchemy-an-intro-to-mvc-and-crud/

Comment: I will definitely read those links, I honestly had never thought of using a sqlite database. As far as the Excel file being read, that is an optional file that can be used to add more data to the output and/or refine the output results. Wish I could go into more details about what exactly everything does and is for.

Comment: How well do you think this will handle data that changes on a daily basis, sometimes as often as hourly?

Comment: It would work fine. I had an objectlistview widget that updated up to every minute. It was set up to download updates from one or more databases. I think I had it set to default to every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely work on implementing this into what I already have. From what I can see I shouldn't have to make any drastic changes to the output panels if I do it correctly.

Comment: Update: While adding the extra functionality from sqlalchemy I would like to also add a history of sorts. Basically each day that the program is used creates a new table within the database.
So far it appears to be working, though I need to finish up the code, it currently uses the date (minus the time) created by datetime.datetime.today() to name the table.

Comment: That's going to be a lot of tables! Instead, I would just use the creation date or a modified date to keep track of which data is which. Maybe do a table dump and save the dump to a row in your history table as a blob or something.

Comment: My apologies for the delayed answer acceptance, it has been a busy weekend. I haven't fully implemented sqlalchemy with all aspects of the app just yet. In fact, still working on the filtering a little bit, but it appears that is more of my "skill" with Python programming than anything else.

Comment: Everything is now working as originally desired, and now that I sit back to look at the finished work I want to make changes already. Using the links provided I have an AUI Managed notebook with 3 tabs, where the first tab is for input and the remaining tabs are output. The initial use of the program requires the 3 files I want to compare, but thanks to the sqlite database I can close and reopen without the need to select anything. Plus filtering was a breeze once I learned how the queries worked. Thank you again!